# Solution for a fixed, dynamic height element to take space

Tags: css, fixed

First of all, I am searching for a pure CSS solution. I can do it really easily with JavaScript, so don't bother giving me hint on how to do it in JS.

I have a web page with 3 container. 2 of them are fixed, the other one is static.

I want to give the static container a padding top and bottom equal to the fixed container.

The first fixed element have a fixed height, so that's not a problem, i give a padding equal to the height :

```
#header{
    height : 100px;
    position : fixed;
}

#content{
    padding-top : 100px;
}
```

But the second fixed element is dynamic since we are using a CMS. Some element can be added by the client and we want the layout to adjust automatically.

You can easily see what i'm trying to do in this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Q59s/1/), just uncomment the JS to see the desired Result.

---

*P.S.: I support iE8 and older.*

*P.P.S.: I am totally aware that it may be impossible w/o JS. If so, just tell me in comment.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `#header` and `#footer` are fixed positioned, they are taken out of the document flow and have no relationship to `#content` anymore.

Therefor you have to options (imho).

1) give the footer a fixed height, so you can do the padding trick, same as with your header.

2) use Javascript, since there is no pure CSS solution (except for 1. point).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i was afraid that would be the case. I guess i'll accept your answer even if i said *"I am totally aware that it may be impossible w/o JS. If so, just tell me in comment."* ;)

Comment: Therefor I gave two "solutions" :))